t3sbootstrap with customScss
Good morning everyone,
is anyone here using t3sbootstrap? I can’t manage to include a custom.scss file and could use some support.
The system behaves as if my custom-variables.scss file doesn’t exist.
Does anyone have an idea and can help me out?
Thanks,
Markus
Setup:

TYPO3 12.4.23 composer installation
t3sbootstrap 5.3.18
t3sb_package current git version (dev-main)

In the constants, I’ve set bootstrap.customScssPath to EXT:<my_sitepackage>/Resources/Public/Scss/. In this directory, I have a custom-variables.scss and a custom-styles.scss. I’ve run the scheduler task t3sbootstrap:customScss multiple times (without any errors), cleared the temporary files, but still, nothing changes – not even an error message.
I'd want to change the primary color globally, but nothings happens. No error occured.

The t3sbootstrap extension offers two methods for managing custom SCSS properties:

Storing in fileadmin:

Location: fileadmin/T3SB/Resources/Public/T3SB-SCSS/


Storing in the t3sb_package Extension:

Location: EXT:t3sb_package/Resources/Public/T3SB-SCSS/



In order to activate the second option :

Enable Custom SCSS: In Config/System/settings.php, set customScss = 1 and sitepackage = 1.
Execute t3sbootstrap:cdnToLocal cron job in order to move JS and CSS files from CDN to local [ under t3sb_package extension ].
Edit custom.scss and custom-variables.scss files under EXT:t3sb_package/Resources/Public/T3SB-SCSS/ folder as needed.
Clean up temporary files located at typo3temp/assets/t3sbootstrap/css/.
Clear Backend Caches.

Important Notes:

Custom SCSS files must be named custom.scss and custom-variables.scss to be recognized.
If you want to include additional SCSS files from a custom extension (e.g., my_sitepackage), you must @import your SCSS into the t3sb_package custom SCSS files. Without this, your custom SCSS will not be applied.


Thank you so much,  Haythem Daoud!
Your tips, explanations, and the guide were exactly what I was looking for. It solved my problem.
The inclusion of my own SCSS files from my site package using @import didn’t work. It works from the same directory but not from another package. Currently, I’m using symlinks as a workaround.
